# Accessing Virtual Hosts from a VM (Running on the Same Box)

Tags: configuration, apache2

I am running Apache with several virtual hosts on my Mac. I think the virtual hosts have properly been configured; thus, I can access the following from the web browser:

- `host1.mydomain`
- `host2.mydomain`
- `host3.mydomain`

I can also access `localhost` with no problem.

However, I can't access those hosts from a virtual machine (I use Parallels Desktop, running on the same box). Do I need to configure something on my virtual machine? Maybe the hosts file, etc.?

Is it also possible to hit those hosts from the virtual machine, even I am not connected to the Internet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this can be solved by simply updating the *hosts* file in the VM.

Assuming the Mac's IP is a.b.c.d and you want to access `host1.mydomain`, you'd need to add this line to the *hosts* file (in the VM):

```
a.b.c.d   host1.mydomain
```

So, when you type in `host1.mydomain` on the VM browser, it will get resolved to the host running on the Mac.